# Why does Parslet (in Ruby) return an empty array when parsing an empty string literal?

Tags: ruby, parsing, parslet

I'm playing with parslet. This is trivial parser which shows me some non-obvious behavior.

```
require 'parslet'

class Parser < Parslet::Parser
  rule(:quote) { str('"') }
  rule(:escape_char) { str('\\') }
  def quoted(term)
    quote >> term >> quote
  end
  rule(:string) {
    quoted( (escape_char >> any | quote.absent? >> any).repeat.as(:string) )
  }
end
```

Obviously, It should parse double-qouted string. And it does. But following result seems strange for me.

```
Parser.new.string.parse '""'
```

This code returns `{:string=>[]}`. Why `empty array` there but not `empty string`? What am I missing?

I'm using `ruby 2.1.1` and `parslet 1.6.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR; - As a rule Parslet's `as` applied to `repeat` captures an array of matches; except in the special case where all the matches are raw strings, in which case it joins them and returns the resulting string.

In your code, the `repeat` doesn't know the types it would capture as there aren't any, so it returns the empty array.

In this example... the empty array seems like the right choice.

```
require 'parslet'

class Parser < Parslet::Parser
  rule(:quote) { str('"') }
  rule(:escape_char) { str('\\') }
  def quoted(term)
    quote >> term >> quote
  end
  rule(:string) {
    quoted( (escape_char >> any | quote.absent? >> any).as(:char).repeat.as(:string) )
  }
end

puts Parser.new.string.parse('""').inspect # => {:string=>[]}
puts Parser.new.string.parse('"test"').inspect 
    # =>  {:string=>[{:char=>"t"@1}, {:char=>"e"@2}, {:char=>"s"@3}, {:char=>"t"@4}]}
```

When the child nodes are just strings Parslet concatenates then into a single string. When there are no elements in the collection it defaults to empty collection instead of empty string.

`maybe` is different.

From http://kschiess.github.io/parslet/parser.html # Repetition and its Special Cases

> These all map to Parslet::Atoms::Repetition. Please note this little
>   twist to #maybe:
>
> str('foo').maybe.as(:f).parse('')         # => {:f=>nil}
>   str('foo').repeat(0,1).as(:f).parse('')   # => {:f=>[]} The
>
> ‘nil’-value of #maybe is nil. This is catering to the intuition that
>   foo.maybe either gives me foo or nothing at all, not an empty array.
>   But have it your way!